# LINQ query(Lambda Expressions) and String.Join

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How to write a Strng.Join for this type of LINQ query(Lambda expression)? (var b will return number of integer lists)

1.

```
var b = braughtForwardInvoices
    .Where(x => x.LinkedTransaction != null 
             && x.LinkedTransaction.Count > 0)
    .Select(x => x.LinkedTransaction.Select(x => x.TransactionId))
    .ToList();
```

Below show the actual working query. I need to write the code in number 1 like number 2.

2.

```
var braughtForwardPaymentId = 
    from item in braughtForwardInvoices
   where item.LinkedTransaction != null 
      && item.LinkedTransaction.Count > 0
  select string.Join(",", item.LinkedTransaction.Select(x => x.TransactionId)).ToString();
```

Comment: You haven't said what you want to get so it's hard to imagine what you want to get: items separated by a coma, a space, or put one item per line, or anything else like `string.Join(what, list)`, how to know 

Comment: I see the code added: what is the difficulty? `.Select(x => string.Join(",", x.LinkedTransaction.Select(t => t.TransactionId)).ToString()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Take the list and send it to string.Join.

```
var b = braughtForwardInvoices.Where(x => x.LinkedTransaction != null 
                                       && x.LinkedTransaction.Count > 0)
                              .Select(x => x.LinkedTransaction.Select(x => x.TransactionId))
                              .ToList();


var result = string.Join(",", b);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the selected IDs as a CSV string, you can join the resulting `IEnumerable`:

```
var b = string.Join(", ", braughtForwardInvoices.Where(x => x.LinkedTransaction != null 
                                           && x.LinkedTransaction.Count > 0)
                                  .Select(x => x.LinkedTransaction.Select(x => x.TransactionId)));
```